# gcc does not find template specialization

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, template-specialization

My network code uses template specialization to serialize types that can not simply be copied. I defined a general template

```
template<typename T> struct TypeHandler
```

that handles all types that can be transported by a simple `memcpy` and then I define specializations for all other types. The problem now is that I have a file with multiple such specializations and if I compile the code with Visual Studio everything works fine. But with gcc all template specializations in that file get used with the exception of

```
template<> struct TypeHandler<uint32_t>
```

which variable length encodes the integer to save space.

Namespaces are the same for all TypeHandler versions and they are even in the same file. But for some reason gcc decides to use the generalized version and I don't really know why.

EDIT:

It seems that gcc uses the instantiation of TypeHandler from an other project that this one links against but doesnt have a specialization for uint32_t even so it transmits uint32_t fields. GCC doesnt give me any error though. How can i tell gcc to use the specialization like Visual Studio does ?

EDIT2:

managed to generate an SSCCE http://netload.in/dateiz3R4eTVqi3/src.tar.gz.htm
the bug here is the other way around but well.

EDIT3:
fixed filesize : http://netload.in/dateixP6iOvc6bD/src.zip.htm

Comment: Can you show the code that you are expecting to call the `uint32_t` specialization? Most likely it's that GCC doesn't define a type to use uint32_t for the type you're expecting.

Comment: thats the code: http://pastebin.com/ALMjQnyw if i run that with the QtCreator it steps into the general TypeHandler as struct TypeHandler<unsigned int>

Comment: It's possible the debugger is lying to you. Put some `std::cout` in to see which specialization is really called.

Comment: Can you post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) please?

Comment: @Oktalist i stepped deeper into the func and it does what the base handler does but i added the cout to be safe and it does indeed call the non specialized one

Comment: @rubenvb i would if i could but when i only use the essential parts it does work. I dont really know what i can do to find out where it fails. I tried renaming the file to fix include order, i searched for all references to the TypeHandler class to see if maybe it was somewhere instantiated with uint32_t before the specialization was visible but i didnt find anything.

Comment: The most likely explanation is undefined behavior  due to instantiating the base template before the specialization is declared. Without code, there's not much we can do to help you find it.

Comment: Build an SSCCE. This is the *only* way to get help that works.

Comment: I doubt anyone would download a 11MB "shortest" compilable example to help you figure out what's going on.

Comment: well its 6 source files with like 10 lines of code max/file i dont know why tar means it needs 11mb

Answer (score 3):

Minimized to:

`test1.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>

template<typename T>
struct TypeHandler
{
    void Print() { std::cout << "base" << std::endl; }
};


void test1()
{
    std::cout << "p1" << std::endl;
    TypeHandler<uint32_t>().Print();
}
```

`test2.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>

template<typename T>
struct TypeHandler
{
    void Print() { std::cout << "base" << std::endl; }
};

template<>
struct TypeHandler<uint32_t>
{
    void Print() { std::cout << "int" << std::endl; }
};

void test2()
{
    std::cout << "p2" << std::endl;
    TypeHandler<uint32_t>().Print();
}
```

`main.cpp`:

```
void test1();
void test2();
int main(){
    test1();
    test2();
}
```

On Windows/MinGW 4.8.2, compiling with `g++ test1.cpp test2.cpp main.cpp -o test` and running produces

```
p1
base
p2
base
```

while using `g++ test2.cpp test1.cpp main.cpp -o test` produces

```
p1
int
p2
int
```

This is a straightforward standard violation causing undefined behavior. You can't explicitly specialize the same template in one translation unit but not the other. The explicit specialization is not visible in `test1.cpp`, causing the compiler to generate an implicit instantiation from the base template. So you get two `TypeHandler<uint32_t>` specializations, and in this instance it appears that the linker decided to pick the one from the first object file it saw. From §14.7.3 [temp.expl.spec]/p6 of the standard  (emphasis mine):

> If a template, a member template or a member of a class template is
>   explicitly specialized then **that specialization shall be declared
>   before the first use of that specialization that would cause an
>   implicit instantiation to take place, in every translation unit in
>   which such a use occurs**; no diagnostic is required. If the program
>   does not provide a definition for an explicit specialization and
>   either the specialization is used in a way that would cause an
>   implicit instantiation to take place or the member is a virtual member
>   function, the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.  An
>   implicit instantiation is never generated for an explicit
>   specialization that is declared but not defined.

Also, obligatory quote of the next paragraph (emphasis mine):

> The placement of explicit specialization declarations for function
>   templates, class templates, member functions of class templates,
>   static data members of class templates, member classes of class
>   templates, member  enumerations of class templates, member class
>   templates of class templates, member function templates of class
>   templates, member functions of member templates of class templates,
>   member functions of member templates of non-template classes, member
>   function templates of member classes of class templates, etc., and the
>   placement of partial specialization declarations of class templates,
>   member class templates of non-template classes, member class templates
>   of class templates, etc., can affect whether a program is well-formed
>   according to the relative positioning of the explicit specialization
>   declarations and their points of instantiation in the translation unit
>   as specified above and below. **When writing a specialization, be
>   careful about its location; or to make it compile will be such a trial
>   as to kindle its self-immolation.**

Comment: but that is not what i am intending to do p1 is a dll/so and p2 is an exe/elf that loads p1. p1 gets linked agains p1_net p2 against p2_net p1_net and p2_net never see each other (atleast should). try comenting out m.Test(). then m2.Test() will print base

Comment: @ACB Do you want everything to use the specialized version?

Comment: no i want P1Msg to print base and P2Msg to print int

Comment: @ACB Well, your `p2` is linking against `p1_net` since it needs to pull `P1Msg` in, along with everything in it. Besides, it's still one program as far as the standard is concerned, so you still have undefined behavior. DLLs do not make a separate program.

Comment: ye my real code doesn pull anything from the p1_net code since i dont need anything in there. just couldnt figure out how to show the problem in the small sample since gcc wouldnt let me define a static var in the dll to print out the values

Comment: @ACB Like I said, as far as the standard is concerned, you have just one program - a shared library is not a separate program. So when you link together things with different definitions of the same template specialization, it's an error as far as the standard is concerned, and gcc is under no obligation to support that. I would make the two projects use different templates.

Comment: but gcc cant just expect that symbols from some random static lib are exported by every executable that links against the so oO

Comment: @ACB Again, you shouldn't be doing this at all...it's not really legal under the standard. However, the direct cause here appears to be CMake linking your main executable against all of your shared library's dependencies as well. Use [LINK_PRIVATE](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html) to mark `p1_net` in your `p1` dependencies should help.