# Do specialized templates require a dedicated declaration?

Tags: c++, templates, linker, template-specialization

I want a templated function that is only defined for certain types, so I write:

```
/* --- header file with just a declaration --- */
template<class T>
void myFunction(T arg);

/* --- cpp file with specialized definition --- */
template<>
void myFunction<int>(int arg){
    // mybody
}
```

But I am a bit confused, reading through for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24683940/9153716).
Is the declaration in the header file good enough for the linker to always link to the same specialization (static linkage)? Or do I need to add another:

```
template<>
void myFunction<int>(int arg);
```

in the header to?

Answer (score 1):

The part that you have to look at from the post you've linked is:

> If a template, a member template or a member of a class template is explicitly specialized then **that specialization shall be declared before the first use of that specialization that would cause an implicit instantiation to take place, in every translation unit in which such a use occurs** [...]

You can create such declaration through explicit instantiation declaration which tells the compiler that the explicit specialization is located somewhere else.

in the header file you can declare the explicit instantiation as

```
extern template void myFunction(int)
```